# sql statement, now - 6 months in unix/epoch time

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp, epoch

my database is using an integer in epoch time for date in this table.

I want to do something like this:

`select * from myTable where date_column > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 6 months`

I'm not sure how to get 6 months out of this, dynamically. And the result of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 6 months` would have to be in epoch time

insight appreciated

Comment: what version of sql are you using?

Comment: postgres, not sure finer details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Postgres, I believe the correct syntax is:

```
date_column > EXTRACT('epoch' from (NOW() - interval ' 6 months'))
```

or similarly:

```
to_timestamp(date_column) > (NOW() - interval ' 6 months'))
```

You can read the complete documentation of the [date/time functions for Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) for more information

Comment: okay, I feel like this is closer to the mark for me, but my date_column is storing epoch time as integers, c'est la vie, how can I do this comparison?  `date_column>NOW() - Interval '6 months`

Comment: thank you, can you take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211408/sql-return-dates-where-there-are-no-results

Answer (score 2):

In MSSQL you can use

```
select * 
from myTable 
where date_column > dateadd(month,-6,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: just found out dateadd method is not within postgres, I'll put postgres in the tag

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT *
  FROM myTable 
 WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(date_column) > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6 MONTH';
```

**Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/51640/4)**