# sql return dates where there are no results

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, epoch

I want to get a table of results showing the dates that X has entries

```
SELECT count(*),
       date_column
FROM myTable
WHERE X
GROUP BY date_column
ORDER BY date_column DESC
```

This works, but I would also like to see the dates where X does not have entries, in my use case this would be intermediary dates.

So for instance 2013-3-10 would be in the results, but the next date would be 2013-3-5, yet I need my result to also return the days where count = 0, so in this case, the 6th, 7th, 8th and 9th

how would I format my query to include those extra times?

Comment: What db? You have to left join with a generated table of dates. PG for example has generate_series for this but other db may require other hacks.

Comment: SQL doesn't create data.  So you'd either have to have a source of all possible dates and left join them in or you just have to build it when you go to display your results such that a NULL date is a count of 0.  This technique hark ens back to days when storage was expensive so you didn't store 0 data.  the absence of the data was enough and you let your display tools show the 0 if it was needed.

Comment: @xQbert right I am using an ORM that can retrieve the data as an array and I can manipulate it there. Was wondering if there was a way to do it in the query

Comment: @JakubKania I am using postgres, can you elaborate on the `generate_series` method and how I would join that to me other query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mocked up a simple example:

```
SELECT q.date_column, count(f.id) FROM
(SELECT
 generate_series(min(date_column),max(date_column), '1 day') AS date_column
 FROM mytable) AS q
LEFT JOIN mytable AS f
ON q.date_column=f.date_column
GROUP BY q.date_column ORDER BY q.date_column;
```

This generates all dates in the needed range. make sure not to do count(*) or you'll get 1 instead of 0
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/fd4ff/1

Comment: @xQbert it certainly is nice because you don't have to worry if your donor table are big enough. But the same can be done with window functions for MSSQL and Oracle (and PostgreSQL), and variables for MySQL. You just select row_number from a table (or a table cross joined with itself enough times to give you the kind of number you want) and add to date.

Comment: hmmmm, f.id always returns 0 on every date

Comment: @CQM could you show it on sqlfiddle? The example I provided works.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for postgresql:

```
SELECT count(*) as count, datecolumn as date FROM myTable group by datecolumn UNION 
select 0 as count, i::date as date from generate_series('2013-01-01', 
'2013-12-31', '1 day'::interval) i where i not in (select datecolumn from myTable) order by date desc
```